# Flexible relativelayout with list and image button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to create a following kind of layout in android , rite now i have created with fixed height of listview which is causing a problem with different dimension of screens of mobiles.

[image]

Initially when this screen appears a button will be at the bottom side only with empty listview and as an when the items will get added in a list view , it grows but button will remain steady at the bottom.

so far i have written following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cText" 
    android:src="@drawable/c_text"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip"



   />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        />
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cBtn"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="52dip"
        android:src="@drawable/preview" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  < RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="52dip"
    android:src="@drawable/preview" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id//listview01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_above="@+id/cBtn"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            />

< /RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add padding or margin as per your requirement

Comment: Well i tried you code , button is coming into the center but its not aligned to the center , as its laying on the left side.

Comment: did you copy paste the same code.. i have same code posted in my eclipse right now and it is exaclty the design you want. how the button can be in center. it is aligned to the bottom with fill_parent width . it will expanded to full screen

Comment: please see the original code i have mentioned this attribute android:layout_width="150dip" as i don't want the full parent width button.

Comment: Relative layout is the best . I personally use this for most of design

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Button as a footer to List View. The sample code sinppet is shown below

Step1: Create a Button

```
  <Button android:id="@+id/footer"  android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="My Footer" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Step2: Make it as Footer to  the List View

```
ListView myList;
  View footerView;
    ViewGroup footerViewOriginal = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.footer);
        footerView = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.footer,footerViewOriginal);
footerView.findViewById(R.id.footer);
myList.addFooterView(footerView, null, true);
```

Step3: Create on ClickListener and write the action what you want to perform

```
footerView.findViewById(R.id.footer).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
return false;

        }
```